# Analytical expression for step response of digital bessel filter

Tags: python, filtering

If I apply a digital Bessel filter to a perfect step function, I get something that looks like the following:

[image]

The green line is the input step response data sampled at 500kHz, the red line is obtained using the `scipy.signal.lfitler` routine with a 8-pole Bessel low-pass filter at 10kHz, and the blue line is the result of the same filter but using the `scipy.signal.filtfilt`.

Given the signal (either red or blue) is there an analytical form for the response that would allow me to extract the cutoff frequency using a nonlinear fit? Both functions look like a sigmoidal of some kind - is there an analytical formula for it?

The form

[image]

seems to fit both cases quite closely, but not perfectly, and it's not clear what relation the time constant bears to the cutoff frequency.

If I fit that form to the `filtfilt` data, I get a linear relationship between the time constant for the fit, and the time constant for the filter (1/fc), with a slope of about 1/35. I imagine that slope will be a function of the filter order. Can anyone suggest a better analytical form for the fit function?

[image]

Comment: How about looking at the frequency response of your filter? Since you are interested in the cut -off frequency and filter order observing your filter behavior in the frequency instead of the time domain may be a better choice. The frequency response of the Bessel filter is given by Bessel polynomials.

Comment: That's probably how I would arrive at an analytical expression for the time-domain response, by transforming the frequency domain one. Just not sure how to go about it. Doing some reading now.

Comment: How would you extract the cut-off frequency from the step response? Not that it's impossible, but you should really better check the frequency response (as suggested in another comment).

Comment: I don't really care about the cutoff frequency, I am interested in having a functional form that I can fit to a step response. The idea is that I have repeated step responses, close enough together that they do not completely settle in between, and I need to fit the amplitudes of the unfiltered steps. That requires a functional form for a nonlinear fit, and one of the parameters (really the only one I don't have an analytical expression for) is the rise time of the filter - which will certainly be related to the reciprocal cutoff frequency, but it's unclear how.

Comment: You can see a similar application, with a different time response, here: https://pages.nist.gov/mosaic//html/doc/Algorithms.html#adept-2-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an analytical response, though it might not look like you would like to have it:

Your Bessel Filter can be written in Z-Domain as

$$H(z)=K\frac{\prod_{i=0}^7(z-z_i)}{\prod_{i=0}^7(z-p_i)}$$

where $z_i$ are the zeros and $p_i$ are the poles of the z-Transform. Now, to get the step response, you "simply" need to calculate

$$h[n]=\mathcal{Z}^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{z-1}H(z)\right).$$

i.e. you multiply the Z-Transform of the filter with the Z-Transform of a unit-step (which is $z/(z-1)$) and calculate the inverse Z-Transform. If you have access to Mathematica etc. it can do it for you. If not, you would need to perform partial fraction decomposition of the expression and then perform inverse Z-Transform of the several partial fractions.

Comment: Nice and ugly, more or less what I expected. Thanks. I think the analytical form I suggested in the OP is probably a decent enough approximation, though I'll have to do some numerical work to compare with this to be sure.